# Download a video

Tags: python, video, web-scraping

I want to get a copy of the video located here:

http://www.sirecam.com/sales/Tattersalls_October_Yearling_Sale/2009

I used inspect element and the video should be located at:
http://www.sirecam.com/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv

but everytime I go to this link I get a 404 error.

I was going to use a small python script with urlretrieve to download this video but I can't seem to find the link to retrieve from.

Any help on how to find the video would be a wonderful learning experience.

Comment: Check your browsers network panel.

Answer (score 2):

**How did I found the real URL using Chrome?**

1. Once http://www.sirecam.com/sales/Tattersalls_October_Yearling_Sale/2009 loaded, open `Developer Tools`:

[image]

2. Select the Network tab options according to the case on matter.

[image]

3. Click play (on the video) and see loaded resources. Then select the "interesting" one and see the URL from where it loads:

[image]

Finally, you could test these steps on another video and see if the prefix/domain from where videos are loaded is the same (http://cdn.sirecam.com/). If it's the same, then just scrape the video path, add the prefix and download it. If it's not the same you would need to dig further.

**Digging further:**

Inside the source code, as you may see in `<param name="flashvars"...` **value** there is some config:

```
config = {
    "key": "#$a13c066f3e6146a6195",
    "clip": {
        "scaling": "orig",
        "autoPlay": true,
        "urlResolvers": "cluster",
        "bufferLength": 6,
        "autoBuffering": true,
        "url": "/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv"
    },
    "contextMenu": [{
        "About Sirecam ...": "function()"
    }],
    "canvas": {
        "backgroundImage": "url(images/sirecam/player_bg_sales.png)",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "plugins": {
        "cluster": {
            "debug": true,
            "url": "images/flowplayer/flowplayer.cluster-3.1.1.swf",
            "hosts": ["http://cdn.sirecam.com", "http://d103cgplnnab87.cloudfront.net", "http://s3.sirecam.com", "http://vdo.sirecam.com"],
            "connectTimeout": 20000,
            "failureExpiry": 20000
        },
        "controls": {
            "borderRadius": 0,
            "timeColor": "rgba(253, 185, 49, 1)",
            "slowForward": true,
            "bufferGradient": "none",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(120, 120, 120, 1)",
            "volumeSliderGradient": "none",
            "slowBackward": false,
            "timeBorderRadius": 20,
            "time": true,
            "progressGradient": "none",
            "height": 22,
            "volumeColor": "rgba(0, 51, 153, 1)",
            "tooltips": {
                "marginBottom": 5,
                "scrubber": true,
                "volume": true,
                "buttons": false
            },
            "opacity": 1,
            "fastBackward": false,
            "timeFontSize": 12,
            "border": "0px",
            "bufferColor": "rgba(0, 51, 153, 1)",
            "volumeSliderColor": "rgba(253, 185, 49, 1)",
            "buttonColor": "rgba(209, 209, 209, 1)",
            "mute": false,
            "autoHide": {
                "enabled": false,
                "hideDelay": 500,
                "hideStyle": "move",
                "mouseOutDelay": 500,
                "hideDuration": 400,
                "fullscreenOnly": true
            },
            "backgroundGradient": [0.5, 0.2, 0],
            "width": "100pct",
            "display": "block",
            "sliderBorder": "1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7)",
            "buttonOverColor": "#ffffff",
            "fullscreen": true,
            "timeBgColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)",
            "scrubberBarHeightRatio": 0.2,
            "bottom": 0,
            "stop": false,
            "zIndex": 1,
            "sliderColor": "#000000",
            "scrubberHeightRatio": 0.6,
            "tooltipTextColor": "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)",
            "spacing": {
                "time": 6,
                "volume": 8,
                "all": 2
            },
            "sliderGradient": "none",
            "timeBgHeightRatio": 0.8,
            "volumeSliderHeightRatio": 0.6,
            "timeSeparator": " ",
            "name": "controls",
            "volumeBarHeightRatio": 0.2,
            "left": "50pct",
            "tooltipColor": "rgba(253, 185, 49, 1)",
            "playlist": false,
            "durationColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "play": true,
            "fastForward": true,
            "progressColor": "rgba(253, 185, 49, 1)",
            "timeBorder": "0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
            "volume": true,
            "scrubber": true,
            "builtIn": false,
            "volumeBorder": "1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7)",
            "margins": [2, 6, 2, 12]
        }
    },
    "playerId": "player",
    "playlist": [{
        "scaling": "orig",
        "autoPlay": true,
        "urlResolvers": "cluster",
        "bufferLength": 6,
        "autoBuffering": true,
        "url": "/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv"
    }]
}
```

Inside that config you'll see something like:

```
"hosts": ["http://cdn.sirecam.com", "http://d103cgplnnab87.cloudfront.net", "http://s3.sirecam.com", "http://vdo.sirecam.com"],
```

Which contains the hosts from where it should serve videos. So in http://www.sirecam.com/sales/Tattersalls_October_Yearling_Sale/2009 you'll see that the path is `/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv` and if you play and try loading the video from those hosts, all of them might work:

- http://cdn.sirecam.com/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv
- http://d103cgplnnab87.cloudfront.net/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv
- http://s3.sirecam.com/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv
- http://vdo.sirecam.com/2009/TOYS/TOYS2009_2.flv

So as you may see, it's a matter of investigation. Then you can develop some script, in your preferred language (Python?), to do those steps and download videos.